# Windows eshell alias command line arguments.. how?

Tags: microsoft-windows, eshell, subprocess, async

I have `alias msexcel (w32-browser "C:/program files/microsoft office/office12/excel.exe")` and this means I can do `msexcel` from eshell and an asynchronous MS Excel will begin to run.

I am looking for ways to do `msexcel "C:\\documents\ and\ settings\\me\my\ documents\\book.xlsx"`.

`alias msexcel (w32-browser (format "C:/program files/microsoft office/office12/excel.exe /r %s" $1))` returns the error message `(void-variable $1)`.

How do I send Excel a file name through this eshell alias?

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying out things since posting the question.  I came up with what works for me.  eshell alias felt too complicated.  Perhaps even this is too complicated.

```
(if (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
  (defun eshell/w32-launch (&rest args)
    (w32-browser (if (eq nil args)
                     "."
                     (car args)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend instead of a an alias to open Excel with a specific
file, an alias to open a file with whatever application it is
associated with:

```
alias o w32-shell-execute open $1
```